# Get value from JSON data from Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I receive a JSON data from my Firebase Real Time Database-

This is the Json:

```
var data={
"07:08:2017_16:57:48": {
"fech": "07:08:2017",
"hor": "16:57:48",
"lat": -41.1515438,
"lng": -71.4083591,
"telef": ""
},
"07:08:2017_16:58:04": {
"fech": "07:08:2017",
"hor": "16:58:04",
"lat": -41.1515438,
"lng": -71.4083591,
"telef": "2944895972"
},
"07:08:2017_16:58:05": {
"fech": "07:08:2017",
"hor": "16:58:05",
"lat": -41.1515438,
"lng": -71.4083591,
"telef": "2944895972"
 }
 }
```

I need the lat values, but I dont understand how use the index on this case

I tried this:

```
var dataj= JSON.parse(data);
var latitud1= dataj[1];
```

any help?

Comment: Note that there is no JSON shown in the question: your `data` variable is already referencing an object that doesn't need to be parsed. You can use a `for..in` loop to iterate over the properties of your object, or `Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) { console.log(data[key].lat) })`.

Comment: I will try without parsing

Comment: You can index with this syntax: `dataj['07:08:2017_16:57:48'].lat`, because the keys are not just alphanumeric.

Comment: the key are date and time  generated , so never have the same name , thats why i need use an index selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have that JavaScript structure, this code will print the latitude values:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(data[key].lat);
});
```

Runnable snippet:

```js
var data = {
    "07:08:2017_16:57:48": {
        "fech": "07:08:2017",
        "hor": "16:57:48",
        "lat": -41.1515438,
        "lng": -71.4083591,
        "telef": ""
    },
    "07:08:2017_16:58:04": {
        "fech": "07:08:2017",
        "hor": "16:58:04",
        "lat": -41.1515438,
        "lng": -71.4083591,
        "telef": "2944895972"
    },
    "07:08:2017_16:58:05": {
        "fech": "07:08:2017",
        "hor": "16:58:05",
        "lat": -41.1515438,
        "lng": -71.4083591,
        "telef": "2944895972"
    }
};
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(data[key].lat);
});
```